# Is there an adjective of tense?

Tags: single-word-requests

While writing some text, I used the phrase "tensal structure" in order to refer to a structure of tense. To my surprise, "tensal" is not a word. What is the correct equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

Simply use it as a **compound noun**, that is , a noun that modifies another noun, so;

**tense structure** should work out just fine.